# CSS-Menu jumps when clicked on

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on the following project and I'm having a small problem with my entire page shifting about 5-10px when the page content goes beyond a certain lenght.

http://www.thewaymultimedia.com/IML/

I'm not sure what I"m missing, I've spent the past couple of hours looking at my CSS to see if I have an extra padding or margin but I cant narrow it down. Anyone a pro at CSS familiar with this problem.

If you go in the about menu and then click on 'board of directors" menu and you will see what i mean. If i reduce the content it will stop, but this page will require quite of bit of vertical real state.

Any suggestions. The website is using WordPress by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possibly because it is going beyond the length of the window and is, therefore, needing a scroll bar?

Comment: I believe you guys are right. any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: You can either force a scroll bar at all times on your pages `body { overflow-x: scroll; }` (possibly) or accept the fact that there will be a scroll bar, which is far more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to the scrollbar...

Comment: Thanks, any idea how fix it? reduce the width?

Comment: How is this not an answer? `I'm not sure what I"m missing`, `That is due to the scrollbar`. Question and answer.